# Expected value of a random variable with unbounded upper limit on one of the outcomes

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Imagine you have a loaded die with a known number of sides, e.g 6. All the sides have a known given probability, and all sides but one have a known outcome; the last side has an unbounded outcome. E.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6+ (6 or more).

Also, we can assume that the outcome of the last side is 6 most of the times and the PMF decreases somehow exponentially (the probability distribution is not given but we can definitely say that the values 7, 8,... are less and less probable).

Is it possible to compute/estimate/say something about the EV for this random variable somehow? Is it that bad to simply consider 6 for the outcome of the last side?

Comment: If the probability of outcomes beyond 5 can be bounded above by an exponentially decreasing function, then yes, the expectation will indeed be finite. An example of such a situation would be "if you roll "6+, add 5 to the total and roll again".

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your application is, and any prior/theoretical knowledge, probably. You could say something if you made certain assumptions about how the tail decreases. For example, if you assumed it was a hurdle-like model structure, you could say define the random variable in two parts

$$
X \sim \text{Multinomial}(n=1, k = 6, p = (p_1, \cdots, p_5, p_{6+}))
$$

and then

$$
Y =
\begin{cases}
X & \text{if $X \in (1, \cdots, 5)$}\\
\text{Pois}(\lambda) +6& \text{otherwise (i.e. $k = \text{6+}$)}
\end{cases}
$$

Which in this case is like a Multinomial-Poisson hurdle model. This is just a made up example, you really should tailor it to your particular needs.